# Azure Service Bus for resending pending notifications

Tags: signalr, azureservicebus

I've created an application using SignalR to send notifications to machines.
Now, if the machine is online, notification is being sent. But if machine is offline, it just gets dropped and won't be sent again.

I am wondering if Azure Service Bus can be used for this purpose wherein such notifications which are dropped from offline machines can be stored in Azure Service Bus and then later on when machine comes online then it will receive this notifications.

Is something like this possible? Or any other approach which can be used for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Yes, service bus is one of the possible solutions as Service Bus is used to decouple applications and acts as messaging broker where if receiver application is done then still the sender application can send the message to the service bus. Once your receiver application is up now, they can start receiving the message. To learn more about service bus and its features you start with [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview).